# Jenkins jacoco plugin

Tags: hudson, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jacoco

I  noticed that the jacoco plugin for jenkins whitout sonar is released, my question is how do I make the configuration in my `pom.xml`? I have made the `jacoco.exec` but how can I use the jacoco plugin to make the `.xml` file? I found it on github([Jacoco Plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jacoco-plugin/))

I've downloaded the zip and tried to compile it whit maven but I get error

```
The project org.jenkins-ci.plugins:jacoco:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT (D:\Projects\jenkinsci-jacoco-plugin\pom.xml) has 1 error
Non-resolvable parent POM for org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:1.424.6: Could not transfer artifact org.jenkins-ci:jenkins:pom:1.21 from/to repo.jenkins-ci.org (http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/): 
Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/jenkins/1.21/jenkins-1.21.pom @ org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:1.424.6, 
C:\Documents and Settings\ro1v0367\.m2\repository\org\jenkins-ci\plugins\plugin\1.424.6\plugin-1.424.6.pom, line 4, column 11 -> [Help 2]
```

What are the steps for the jacoco plugin, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Those who want to try jacoco plugin now has very good test coverage relased a few months and does not require sonar to work on Jenkins especially. Some useful links for those interested:

- http://java.dzone.com/articles/jacoco-jenkins-plugin
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JaCoCo+Plugin
- http://www.agile-engineering.net/2012/01/unit-test-code-coverage.html

Cheers,